# Repeat a single row in all rows Oracle grouped

Tags: oracle, row, repeat

I need to repeat the car answer in all rows until the next survey set of answer.

The example I need is in the last column.

The need is with this way, I can create a car parameter filter to fetch all the answer rows.

I've tried some ways but no success.

Is that possible?

Thanks a lot for any help.

```
surv_id date_time   question_id question    answer_id   answer  car
CAR_CHECK1  30/03/2022 08:42    5169    type    4509    return to supplier  RMN9H51
CAR_CHECK1  30/03/2022 08:43    5132    date_time   4624    2022-03-30-08.43.00 RMN9H51
CAR_CHECK1  30/03/2022 08:43    5174    car group   4629    V   RMN9H51
CAR_CHECK1  30/03/2022 08:48    5134    car 4632    RMN9H51 RMN9H51
CAR_CHECK1  30/03/2022 08:48    5135    car km  4633    51389   RMN9H51
CAR_CHECK1  30/03/2022 08:48    5142    picture 4634    YES RMN9H51
CAR_CHECK1  30/03/2022 08:55    5166    signature   4627    SIGNATURE   RMN9H51
CAR_CHECK1  30/03/2022 10:42    5169    type    4509    return to supplier  AAA1525
CAR_CHECK1  30/03/2022 10:43    5132    date_time   4624    2022-03-30-08.43.00 AAA1525
CAR_CHECK1  30/03/2022 10:43    5174    car group   4629    V   AAA1525
CAR_CHECK1  30/03/2022 10:48    5134    car 4632    AAA1525 AAA1525
CAR_CHECK1  30/03/2022 10:48    5135    car km  4633    51389   AAA1525
CAR_CHECK1  30/03/2022 10:48    5142    picture 4634    YES AAA1525
CAR_CHECK1  30/03/2022 10:55    5166    signature   4627    SIGNATURE   AAA1525
CAR_CHECK1  01/04/2022 10:42    5169    type    4509    return to supplier  CCC1122
CAR_CHECK1  01/04/2022 10:42    5132    date_time   4624    2022-03-30-08.43.00 CCC1122
CAR_CHECK1  01/04/2022 10:42    5174    car group   4629    V   CCC1122
CAR_CHECK1  01/04/2022 10:42    5134    car 4632    CCC1122 CCC1122
CAR_CHECK1  01/04/2022 10:42    5135    car km  4633    51389   CCC1122
CAR_CHECK1  01/04/2022 10:42    5142    picture 4634    YES CCC1122
CAR_CHECK1  01/04/2022 10:42    5166    signature   4627    SIGNATURE   CCC1122
```

[image]

Comment: The output you have supplied is it the desired output, if so, please share source data-set sample too. Also, provide query you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi, follow the sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wb6fDJ16SBDFqhPDrNg8UqC_Eelcs37A/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117790606028929763718&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: This sheet is same as present in question, is it the output or source data-set? Its still not very clear what you need.

Comment: Sorry not to be clear. The source I have is excel given without the last collumn. I need to replicate the car answer to one separate collumn to be able to filter as a parameter.

Comment: So from where will you fetch that column values. I understand that you need to repeat based on quest/Ans set. To give an idea you can use window function with partition over question order by question and populate car column based on that. If you share more input as to from where the value of car is being fetched I can try and formulate a query. Is it like table_1 has what you shared in spread sheet minus car col and table-2 has car values and some id column. You need to combine both to get output you have shared?

Comment: pl see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fdf9b9/1  the sample data (without "car" column) shows that there is NOTHING in that sample data that ties rows 1 to 7 together, or rows 8 to 15 together, or the final 7 rows. i.e. only you can see the relationship, but there is nothing in the raw data that does it.  **Are there ANY other columns in your raw data?** (supply all of those in sample data).  Particularly any extra columns that would help to  link the groups of 7 rows. Note that the "date_time" column indicates grouping but it isn't reliable because 2 or more surveys coudl occur at the same time